# How can I force PHP to render fatal errors as plain text?

Tags: php

On my development machine, I have PHP set to display all errors (i.e., `display_errors` is set to `on`). Unfortunately, PHP sends fatal errors as `text/html`, which makes reading call stacks a bit of a pain as whitespace is ignored in HTML.

Is there a way to have PHP send pages as `text/plain` for fatal errors?

Comment: Do you have `html_errors` turned on? `php --ini | fgrep html_error`

Comment: @MikePurcell I do now: although I asked about how to get plain text error messages, that actually accomplishes the spirit of what I want to do nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Was a total guess, what pushed me to ask that was what you said about "which makes reading call stacks a bit of a pain". In all honesty I use XDebug, which makes reading stack traces very easy. Would you mind if I post as a solution for acceptance?

Comment: @MikePurcell It technically doesn't answer the question as asked, and rewriting the question after the fact wouldn't be fair to those who already answered. I suppose I could ask a new question about how to pretty-print errors in PHP...

Comment: Nah it's fine, dis-regard. Feel like a points whore even asking lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [few people in the comments](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#91535) on PHP.net's `set_error_handler()` entry suggested using [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to capture fatal errors. Sure enough, it worked.

I created a file, `error.php`, with the following:

```
register_shutdown_function('plain_text_error');

function plain_text_error() {
  if ($e = error_get_last()) {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
  }
}
```

Then added the following to my dev site's `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/error.php
```

And voilà, fatal errors rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php set your own error handler and then either set the desired mime-type or output everything in between `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: Using `set_error_handler()` doesn't seem to intercept `E_ERROR`s.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot intercept fatal errors in PHP. As Mike Purcell says, turning off [html_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors) in your PHP config will probably allow you to return plain error messages without formatting.

Comment: Turning off `html_errors` doesn't set the mimetype of the page returned to `text/plain` which is why I asked this question.